# How to choose coefficients to compute surface LaPlacian filtration of analog sensor data?

Tags: analog, filter, laplace-transform

[Surface LaPlacian filtration](http://jallen.faculty.arizona.edu/sites/jallen.faculty.arizona.edu/files/Chapter_22_Surface_Laplacian.pdf) is used (among other things, probably) to [improve spatial resolution](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1114/1.1352642) of analog sensor data, particularly in the context of electroencephalogram (EEG) and the magnetoencephalogram (MEG). I'm trying to use it with my EEG development board in pre-processing for an algorithm that controls a drone's movements.

In several brain-computer interface (BCI) and EEG data pipeline programs (like [OpenViBE](http://openvibe.inria.fr/), Brain Bay, or even the Processing IDE) you can add such a filter to the data pipeline. The only parameters you're asked to provide are hard-coded coefficients.

All I've been able to learn about these coefficients thusfar is that there are 2 per input channel (i.e. 2 per input analog sensor data streams).

[image]

Note in the example photo above I've selected only 4 channels but there are still enough coefficients for 10 channels.

Comment: depends on number of electrodes for 64 choose n=10  =sqrt(#sensors)+2 and \$\lambda=1e-5\$ for smooth

Comment: I'm not an authority on this field, just a reader. But coincidentally it looks exactly like the hand drawn images by Maxwell in his Treatise on Magnetism for 3rd and 4th spherical harmonics i the last few pages of the appendix ( book in archive.org)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Wow, that sounds like quite a tomb. Makes me realize I should've chosen my major more carefully; I'm mainly just a Machine Learning guy with a hobby interest in EE (though I'd love to read and understand something like that). Incidentally, does the equation you gave vary between the coefficients? I mean in the example that comes with OpenViBE there were 10 coefficients for 5 channels (sensors) and the coefficients were all different.

Comment: the goal is to improve spacial S/N ratio for different common band frequencies.  It also depends if you are looking for deeper signals, then it reduces the signal too much.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Well there's one thing you've said that I can understand given my Machine Learning background :)